# Web scraping problem . i am using Beautiful soup and python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need a title, address, phone number, description from this code. So far i have done this. Now I am stuck please help new to Web scraping

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

import urllib.request

import pandas as pd

withurllib.request.urlopen("http://buildingcongress.org/list/category/architects-6") as url:

s = url.read()

page_soup = soup(s, 'html.parser')

listings = []

for rows in page_soup.find_all("div"):

    if ("mn-list-item-odd" in rows["mn-listing mn-nonsponsor mn-search-result-priority-highlight-30"]) or ("mn-list-item-even" in rows["mn-listing mn-nonsponsor mn-search-result-priority-highlight-30"]):

        name = rows.find("div", class_="mn-title").a.get_text()
```

I am getting an error in my for a loop. I am stuck, please help

Comment: please provide the error.

Comment: you are going to need to collect the initial links from the landing page  for each business then visit each of those pages to get all the info

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). I would also suggest that you [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: OP - Please do not deliberately sabotage answers and questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression to search the classes and then iterate.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://buildingcongress.org/list/category/architects-6"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for rows in soup.find_all('div',class_=re.compile('mn-list-item-odd|mn-list-item-even')):
    name = rows.find("div", class_="mn-title").find('a').text
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following as you need to visit each page

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import re

results = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('http://buildingcongress.org/list/category/architects-6')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.mn-title a')]
    for link in links:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        name = soup.select_one('[itemprop="name"]').text
        address = re.sub(r'\n|\r', ' ' , ' '.join([item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('.mn-address1, .mn-citystatezip')]))
        tel = soup.select_one('.mn-member-phone1').text
        desc = re.sub(r'\n|\r','',soup.select_one('#about .mn-section-content').text) if soup.select_one('#about .mn-section-content') else 'No desc'
        row = [name, address, tel, desc]
        results.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['name', 'address', 'tel', 'desc'])
print(df)
```